# How to do a simple XML Parser with Android

Tags: android, xml, dom

Hell there, I have been stuck on this for a bit now.  I know it should be simple but I can't seem to find where I went wrong.  I built my little XML parser after following and trying to adapt the DOM Parser example here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html I have it recognising the nodes but I, for the life of me, can't figureout why it is telling me the value of the nodes is "null".  Help would be greatly appreciated.

My XML test file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Person>
    <Name>Scott</Name>
    <Gender>Male</Gender>
    <More>And So On..</More>
</Person>
```

My Parser code is.

```
public class XMLParser {
    InputStream xmlDocument;
    TextView tv;

    public XMLParser(InputStream xmlDocument, TextView tv) {
        this.xmlDocument = xmlDocument;
        this.tv = tv;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> parse() {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        HashMap<String, String> xmlItems = new HashMap<String, String>();
        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document dom = builder.parse(xmlDocument);
            Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();
            NodeList items = root.getElementsByTagName("Person");
            Element rootElement = (Element)items.item(0);
            items = rootElement.getChildNodes();
            tv.append("\nParser, # of Items: " + String.valueOf(items.getLength()));
            for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++){
                Node item = items.item(i);
                xmlItems.put(item.getNodeName(), item.getNodeValue());
                tv.append("\nNM: " + item.getNodeName() + " NV: " + item.getNodeValue());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } 
        return xmlItems;
    }
}
```

Comment: just in case you think your best option is XML - try using [JSON](http://www.json.org/).  [Google GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) makes parsing a no brainer. xml is painful

Comment: I'm going to be that guy and say simple and xml don't belong together :). But JSON is awesome and you should check it out.

Comment: Well it looks simple to me.  I'm getting the file from a website and trying to get the information out of it.  The one here is just a representation of the layout of the file.

Comment: the code involved in parsing XML is far more complex and confusing than JSON's part.  The libraries for JSON seem to be far more advanced and take away the headache. look into it. many webservices offer JSON as on output option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using XmlPullFactory, and it's not **so** bad.

**Edit for Converting to Hashmap**

Note that this isn't really recommended.  This code does **not** check for duplicate keys in the hashmap, and it will overwrite any existing keys!!!

```
public HashMap<String, String> parseXml(String xml) {
    XmlPullParserFactory factory;
    String tagName = "";
    String text = "";
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
    
    try {
        factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml);
        xpp.setInput(sr);
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                text = xpp.getText(); //Pulling out node text
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                tagName = xpp.getName();
                hm.put(tagName, text);
                text = ""; //Reset text for the next node
            }
            eventType = xpp.next();
        }
    }  catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception attribute", e + "+" + tagName);
    }
}
```

Comment: The xml data is not very nested with lots of tags all at the same level.  Is there a way to loop through the data rather than having to specify every single tag?

Comment: Well, the idea with XML (even the sample you gave) is that every element has unique data specific to it.  In the example you gave, if you had a Person object, then when you come across the Person tag, you create a new instance of it.  When you come to the Gender, you set that person's gender based on the value you received

Comment: I'm trying to make a HashMap of all the tag/value pairs so I can reference them later.  There are no duplicate tags.  The simplest idea I had was to just map the tags as the keys and the tag values as the values.

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked like a charm!  You don't mind if I use a modification of it in my little project do you?

Comment: Knock yourself out!  Glad to be of help.

Comment: I think this won't work if you have an XML Parent Tag (anything like: <a> <b> 1</b> <c>2</c> </a>), check my answer below to a answer which use recursive functions which will works with parents tags. I mean with this code you will lose the Parent - Son structure inside the XML because you will just get a list of tags names with values. I mean, using the simple xml I wrote above, after you have applied this function to that XML you will never know, by just looking the result, that "a" has 2 son "b" & "c" because you will lose all information about "a" and about XML structure.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Person is actually the root node here, maybe you don't need `root.getElementsByTagName("Person");`

If your planning on having multiple people maybe change the xml file to     and then change it to `root.getElementsByTagName("Person");`

Comment: Thanks, this simplified my code a bit.  Although it didn't change the null problem.  Even with some debugging it seems the tag nodes don't contain any value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe move away from the IBM example to a simpler example like this one:
http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parseread-xml-data-into-android-listview/

Answer (score 0):

I found the IBM example clunky and messy. I wrote my own thing to handle RSS feeds, it can be adapted to accommodate custom XML feeds.

an example of using this:

save the contents of [this yahoo feed](http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/topstories) into a file and place it on your project. read the file into a string.

```
String fileContents = ...;
XMLFeed feed = XMLUtils.getXmlFeed(fileContents);
```

you now have an object containing a list of each entry from the RSS feed

There are 4 classes below. I have commented some for my own good but it may be confusing for others.

Basically, the `DefaultHandler` looks through the XML string for common RSS names such as description, URL, title, etc. it saves each entry into its own object and adds it to the master list. the constant(final) fields in the `DefaultHandler` class can be changed(add/remove strings) to fit your structure - although you may need to change the structure of the `XmlFeedItem` class too.

You should be able to use this with no changes to standard RSS feeds.

hope it helps

```
public class XMLUtils {
    public static XmlFeed getXmlFeed(String xmlString) {
        XMLHandler handler = null;
        try {
            XMLReader xr = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser().getXMLReader();

            handler = new XMLHandler();
            xr.setContentHandler(handler);

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setEncoding("UTF-8");
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlString));

            xr.parse(is);
        }
        catch(SAXException e) {
            return null;
        }
        catch(ParserConfigurationException e) {
            return null;
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
        return handler.getXmlFeed();
    }
}

public class XMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    /**
     * entity names in the XML document such as <item> which contain many fields
     */
    private static final String OBJECTS[] = new String[] {"item", "entry"};

    /**
     * field names which correspond to a "description"
     */
    private static final String DESCRIPTIONS[] = new String[] {"description", "summary"};

    /**
     * field names which correspond to a "url"
     */
    private static final String URLS[] = new String[] {"link", "id", "guid"};

    /**
     * field names which correspond to "date"
     */
    private static final String PUB_DATES[] = new String[] {"pubDate", "date", "updated", "published", "timestamp"};

    /**
     * field names which correspond to "title"
     */
    private static final String TITLES[] = new String[] {"title"};

    /**
     * the current element being read in
     */
    private String currentElement;
    private boolean foundItem;
    private XmlFeed xmlFeed;
    private XmlFeedItem xmlFeedItem;

    private String object, description, url, pubDate, title;
    public XMLHandler() {
        currentElement = "";
        object = description = url = pubDate = title = null;
        foundItem = false;
        xmlFeed = new XmlFeed();
    }
    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        super.characters(ch, start, length);
        String s = new String(ch, start, length);
        if(foundItem && s.trim().length() > 0) {
            if(isFieldAvailable(currentElement, DESCRIPTIONS, description)) {
                xmlFeedItem.setDescription(xmlFeedItem.getDescription() + s);
            }
            else if(isFieldAvailable(currentElement, URLS, url)) {
                xmlFeedItem.setUrl(xmlFeedItem.getUrl() + s);
            }
            else if(isFieldAvailable(currentElement, PUB_DATES, pubDate)) {
                xmlFeedItem.setPubDate(xmlFeedItem.getPubDate() + s);
            }
            else if(isFieldAvailable(currentElement, TITLES, title)) {
                xmlFeedItem.setTitle(xmlFeedItem.getTitle() + s);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
        super.endDocument();
    }
    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);
        if(isFieldAvailable(localName, OBJECTS, object)) {
            xmlFeed.getItems().add(new XmlFeedItem(xmlFeedItem));
            xmlFeedItem = new XmlFeedItem();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
        super.startDocument();
    }
    /**
     * @param fieldToTest the current element found in the XML string while parsing
     * @param options the array of elements available to match fieldToTest to
     * @param currentField the element that we're currently inside
     * @return <p>if <strong>fieldToTest</strong> is contained in <strong>options</strong> and if <strong>currentField</strong> 
     * is either null or contained in <strong>options</strong>.  This allows us to specify a number of different 
     * fields which mean the same thing in an XML feed.  Example: <strong>summary</strong> may not be included 
     * in a feed but <strong>description</strong> is.  Both <strong>summary</strong> and <strong>description</strong> are contained 
     * in the available <strong>options</strong>, so it is still matched up and used.  Once one element is used 
     * and is contained in <strong>options</strong> it will always use the same element.  <strong>currentField</strong> 
     * is assigned to <strong>fieldToTest</strong> if returning true and if its null(hasn't been matched before)</p>
     */
    private boolean isFieldAvailable(String fieldToTest, String[] options, String currentField) {
        for(String field: options) {
            if(field.equalsIgnoreCase(fieldToTest) && (currentField == null || currentField.equalsIgnoreCase(field))) {
                if(currentField == null) {
                    currentField = new String(fieldToTest);
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);
        currentElement = new String(localName);
        if(!foundItem && isFieldAvailable(localName, OBJECTS, object)) {
            foundItem = true;
            xmlFeedItem = new XmlFeedItem();
        }
    }
    public XmlFeed getXmlFeed() {
        return xmlFeed;
    }
}

public class XmlFeed {
    private List<XmlFeedItem> items;
    public XmlFeed() {
        items = new ArrayList<XmlFeedItem>();
    }
    public List<XmlFeedItem> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
    public void setItems(List<XmlFeedItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}

public class XmlFeedItem {
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String pubDate;
    private String url;
    public XmlFeedItem() {
        title = description = pubDate = url = "";
    }
    public XmlFeedItem(XmlFeedItem rssFeedItem) {
        this.title = rssFeedItem.getTitle();
        this.description = rssFeedItem.getDescription();
        this.pubDate = rssFeedItem.getPubDate();
        this.url = rssFeedItem.getUrl();
    }
    public String getPubDate() {
        return pubDate;
    }
    public void setPubDate(String pubDate) {
        this.pubDate = pubDate;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could use a SAX parser something like:

```
private void parse(String xml) {
        final ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
        Xml.parse(xml, new DefaultHandler() {
            private Person person;
            private StringBuilder builder;

            @Override
            public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
                    String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
                builder = new StringBuilder();
                if(localName.equals("Person")) {
                    person = new Person();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
                    throws SAXException {
                if(localName.equals("Person")) {
                    people.add(person);
                }
                else if(localName.equals("Name")){
                    person.setName(builder.toString());
                }
                else if(localName.equals...) {
                    ... etc
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
                    throws SAXException {
                builder.append(ch, start, length);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Stax/pull is really clunky since the API is pretty low-level and hard to use directly. Please try [Konsume-XML](https://gitlab.com/mvysny/konsume-xml) instead:

```
val file = File("person.xml")
file.konsumeXml().use { k ->
    k.child("Person") {
        println(childText("Name"))
        println(childText("Gender"))
        println(childText("More"))
    }
}
```

This will print

```
Scott
Male
And So On..
```

Answer (score 0):

I share because I didn't found good codes about this answer and I won't add another external library to my project so I did a simple XML Parser which converts XML -> List
Obviously by using the concept anyone can do a better implementation than this lol

I did another XML parser in PhP which only use objects (php is more free about creating customized on the fly objects.) if anyone need just write a comment above and I will share it.

XML parsing recursive functions to parse a Full Trimmed XML String (No space between XML Tags and no \n and \t) and get a List of HashMaps Tree (an HashMap tree is an HashMap which can contains others HashMaps which can contains others HashMaps ecc ecc,
so in code: 
HashMap where T can be HashMap or, for example, String
so
HashMap>>

Usage:

```
DataUtils.parseStringXML(XML.replaceAll("[\\n\\t ]*", "")));
```

Library Code:

(# LoL Edited 10/07/2019 18:00 -> added "lastEvent" to manage empty XML tag)

(# LoL Edited Again 10/07/2019 18:52 -> fixed "lastEvent" to manage empty XML tags)

```
/** XML Parsing Methods **/
public static <T extends Object> List<HashMap<String, T>> parseStringXML(String xml){
    List<HashMap<String, T>> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    if(xml != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(xml)){
        try{
            XmlPullParserFactory xppFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            xppFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            XmlPullParser xpp = xppFactory.newPullParser();
            xpp.setInput(new StringReader(xml));
            ret = parseTagsXML(xpp);
        } catch (XmlPullParserException xppE){
            EMaxLogger.onException(TAG, xppE);
        } catch (Exception e){
            EMaxLogger.onException(TAG, e);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

/** XML Parsing Methods **/
private static <T extends Object> T parseTagsXML(XmlPullParser xpp) {
    int index = 0x0;
    List<HashMap<String, T>> tree = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, T>>(){{add(new HashMap<>());}};
    try{
        List<String> tags = new ArrayList<>();
        int event = 0x0; int lastEvent;
        while(event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
            lastEvent = xpp.getEventType();
            if(lastEvent == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && tags.contains(xpp.getName())){
                tags.remove(xpp.getName());
                if(tags.size() == 0x0){
                    return (T) new HashMap<String, T>(){{put(xpp.getName(), null);}};
                }
            }
            event = xpp.next();
            switch (event){
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    tags.add(xpp.getName());
                    if(tags.size() >= 0x2 && containsStringKeyInMapsTree(tree.get(index), tags.get(tags.size() - 0x2))){
                        tree.set(index, putMapElementInTreeMaps(tags.get(tags.size() - 0x2), tree.get(index), tags.get(tags.size() - 0x1), parseTagsXML(xpp)));
                    } else {
                        tree.get(index).put(tags.get(tags.size() - 0x1), parseTagsXML(xpp));
                    }
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    return (T) xpp.getText();
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if(tags.size() > 0x0 && tags.contains(xpp.getName())) {
                        tags.remove(xpp.getName());
                        if(tags.size() == 0x0){
                            if(xpp.getDepth() == 0x1) {
                                index++;
                                tree.add(new HashMap<>());
                                break;
                            } else {
                                return (T) tree.get(index);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if(lastEvent == XmlPullParser.START_TAG){
                        return null;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        if(tree.size() >= index && (tree.get(index) == null || tree.get(index).isEmpty())) {
            tree.remove(index);
        }
    } catch(IOException ioE){
        EMaxLogger.onException(TAG, ioE);
    } catch(XmlPullParserException xppE){
        EMaxLogger.onException(TAG, xppE);
    }
    return (T) tree;
}

/** Tree HashMap Methods **/
private static <T extends Object> boolean containsStringKeyInMapsTree(HashMap<String, T> tree, String key) {
    if(tree != null){
        if(tree.containsKey(key)){
            return true;
        } else if(tree.size() > 0x0){
            for(String k : tree.keySet()){
                if(k != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(k.trim()) && tree.get(k) != null && tree.get(k) instanceof HashMap && containsStringKeyInMapsTree((HashMap<String, T>) tree.get(k), key)){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private static <T extends Object> HashMap<String, T> putMapElementInTreeMaps(String parentKey, HashMap<String, T> tree, String elementKey, T element){
    if(tree != null){
        if(tree.containsKey(parentKey) && tree.get(parentKey) != null && tree.get(parentKey) instanceof HashMap){
            ((HashMap<String, T>) tree.get(parentKey)).put(elementKey, element);
        } else if(tree.size() > 0x0){
            for(String key : tree.keySet()){
                if(key != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(key.trim()) && tree.get(key) != null && tree.get(key) instanceof HashMap){
                    tree.put(key, (T) putMapElementInTreeMaps(parentKey, (HashMap<String, T>) tree.get(key), elementKey, element));
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return tree;
}
```

It uses recursion.
Maybe if I need I will do an XML parser which converts XML to Generic Objects.
To do that you need to use "pre-determinate" "setter & getter" methods in the Object.
For example for every tag XML you will have a "getTAG_NAME()" and a "setTAG_NAME" method which you will use to set the value inside the object.

To do that you need to use Java - Field and Method classes, for example to set a Object field using is name:

```
public static void setFieldValue(Object obj, Field field, int value){
    try {
        field.setInt(obj, value);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException iacE) {
        EMaxLogger.onException(TAG, iacE);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iarE) {
        EMaxLogger.onException(TAG, iarE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        EMaxLogger.onException(TAG, e);
    }
}
```

So every time you have a new XML_TAG and a new TAG_VALUE then you call the respective "setXML_TAG(TAG_VALUE)" method by using the function above.

The function prototype will be something like:

```
public static <T extends Object> T parseStringXmlToGenericObject(T myObj, String xml){ [...] }
```

Where T is the specific object built to store the XML TAGs Value, for example:

```
 <root_xml_tag>
      <xml_tag_0x1>lol</xml_tag_0x1> 
      <xml_tag_0x2>
           <xml_tag_0x2a>asd</xml_tag_0x2a>
           <xml_ag_0x2b>lmao</xml_tag_0x2b>
      </xml_tag_0x2>
      <xml_tag_0x3>rotfl</xml_tag_0x3>
 </root_xml_tag>
```

If you have anything like the xml Above your object to store XML data will be:

```
public class RootXmlTag {
  private String mXmlTag0x1;
  private XmlTag0x2 mXmlTag0x2;
  private String mXmlTag0x3;

  /** Setter & Getter Methods **/
  public void setxml_tag_0x1(String val){ 
     mXmlTag0x1 = val;
  }

  public String getxml_tag_0x1(){
     return mXmlTag0x1;
  }

  public void setxml_tag_0x2(XmlTag0x2 val){ 
     mXmlTag0x2 = val;
  }

  public XmlTag0x2 getxml_tag_0x2(){
     return mXmlTag0x2;
  }

  [... Ecc Ecc Setter & Getter Methods 4 Every Objects Properties ...]

  [... Other Methods you will need ....]


  /** Inner Classes For Parents XML Tags (Tags with Tags Sons ecc..) **/
  class XmlTag0x2 {

     private String mXmlTag0x2a;
     private String mXmlTag0x2b;

     /** Getter & Setter Methods **/
     [... See Outer Parent Class ...]
  }

}
```

So then when you get an xml tag you just do, really simple example (Proof-Of-Concept [PoC):

```
// Assume having "T myObj" where T = RootXmlTag. 

String xmlTagName = xpp.getName();
event = xpp.next();
String tagValue = xpp.getText();
Utilities.setFieldValue(yourObj, "set".concat(xmlTagName), tagValue);
```

Obviously to do that you need to know how the XML is before parse it (when you won't know that? lol. Obviously you will know how it is, maybe you will have different versions of the xml with differents tags, but you will always know the structure you will get.)

Personally actually I'm using the HashMaps Trees way just because I don't like to create a lot of class just to parse 2 or 3 XMLs, so actually I didn't implemented the Object Way. If I will do that I will share it.

GG
Bye, have a Nice Coding!

(I'd like if anybody post others solution using recursive functions just to compare and learn more methods (: Thank you! bye all)