# How to add a framework to Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, frameworks

I need Simple xml parser for my project. I read throu it's site but i couldnt find how should i add it to my project to use it properly.

I programming in android using eclipse.

[This is the site of Simple.](http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [NoClassDefFoundError - Eclipse and Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247998/noclassdeffounderror-eclipse-and-android)

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070923/how-to-do-a-simple-xml-parser-with-android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do the following:

1. Download jar or zip of the Simple parser [here](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download.php)
2. Copy it into the directory where the libraries of your project is located.
3. Let Eclipse knowing it by adding the library into the classpath

In order for the jar to be available at runtime, you need to:

- Put the jar under your assets folder
- Include this copy of the jar in your build path
- Go to the export tab on the same popup window
- Check the box against the newly added jar

last part is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247998/noclassdeffounderror-eclipse-and-android)